# jni4net - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNet()I

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, jni4net

I've found this library and I loved it so much... But I can't start using it... I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but can anyone help me?

I've read the wiki and environment setup. And I'm trying to do a simple hello world in Java calling C#.

But I'm receiving this error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNet()I`

Here's my Folder setup in Eclipse: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6147142/8265327/e2419670-16cd-11e5-85bd-dae9ea275186.png

Here's my Main Class:

```
package testJni4net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;

import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;
import system.*;
import system.Object;
import system.io.TextWriter;
import system.collections.IDictionary;
import system.collections.IEnumerator;

public class Teste1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create bridge, with default setup
        // it will lookup jni4net.n.dll next to jni4net.j.jar
        Bridge.setVerbose(true);

        Bridge.init();

        // here you go!
        Console.WriteLine("Hello .NET world!\n");

        // OK, simple hello is boring, let's play with System.Environment
        // they are Hashtable realy
        final IDictionary variables = system.Environment
                .GetEnvironmentVariables();

        // let's enumerate all keys
        final IEnumerator keys = variables.getKeys().GetEnumerator();
        while (keys.MoveNext()) {
            // there hash table is not generic and returns system.Object
            // but we know is should be system.String, so we could cast
            final system.String key = (system.String) keys.getCurrent();
            Console.Write(key);

            // this is automatic conversion of JVM string to system.String
            Console.Write(" : ");

            // we use the hashtable
            Object value = variables.getItem(key);

            // and this is JVM toString() redirected to CLR ToString() method
            String valueToString = value.toString();
            Console.WriteLine(valueToString);
        }

        // Console output is really TextWriter on stream
        final TextWriter writer = Console.getOut();
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

And here's the full stack trace:

```
Can't initialize jni4net Bridgenet.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNet()I
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jni4net.inj.INJException: Can't initialize jni4net Bridge
    at net.sf.jni4net.CLRLoader.init(CLRLoader.java:45)
    at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.init(Bridge.java:35)
    at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.init(Bridge.java:31)
    at testJni4net.Teste1.main(Teste1.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNet()I
    at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNet(Native Method)
    at net.sf.jni4net.CLRLoader.init(CLRLoader.java:37)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but this error happened to me on jdk7. So I back to version jni4net 0.8.3 and everything is fine! Sorry for that. But I can't update yet to jdk8 because of another vendor applications that I'm using.